# Drop down div with zurb foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to implement a drop down div similar to that we have when we go to the zurb foundation site http://foundation.zurb.com and click on the cross next the foundation brand. When doing this a div is inserted  between the navbar and the panel.

How can I do something similar using foundation ?

Comment: adding jquery to tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a foundation-specific feature but a jQuery effect, namely `slideDown`.

You can apply this to any element, let's say one of your *foundation rows* that is initially hidden using `display:none;`.

Something like this:

```
$('#actionBtn').bind('click', function() {
    $('#hiddenRow').slideDown();
});
```

[jQuery - slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

[W3Schools - jQuery - slideDown](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.asp)